# Should I use JavaScript to develop Linux (GNOME & Gtk) applications?

Tags: gjs

I've done Python and C apps using Gtk+ and GNOME APIs, and now I see there's support for JavaScript in GNOME 3 thanks to GJS (and I've also heard about seed).

So, I have to ask: does it worth it? I just want to know if GJS has gained attention and is not going to be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gjs is used as the foundation for gnome-shell in GNOME 3 and for [GNOME Shell Extensions](http://extensions.gnome.org) so it is very unlikely to go away or get deprecated, and in fact is seeing [constant improvements all the time](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gjs/log/) so I can't see any reason not to use it if it suits your purpose.